# Sustantivo "elecciones" y el verbo "haber" (¿conjugación singular o plural?)

Tags: subjuntivo, plurales

Tengo una duda con el sustantivo *"elecciones"* y el imperfecto de subjuntivo en un ejercicio. El ejercicio dice así:

> Me alegraba de que __**(haber)**__ nuevas elecciones.

Lo correcto creo que sería *"hubiese o hubiera"* porque *"elecciones"* es un sustantivo con significado singular, no plural, pese a llevar la *"s"* al final. Pero podría ser ¿"hubiesen" o "hubieran"?. No estoy segura.

Comment: El verbo "haber" en ese sentencia va en singular. Puedes encontrar una explicación en la RAE, en la entrada para el verbo "haber", veáse el uso como ["verbo impersonal"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=haber).

Comment: Gracias por el enlace a la RAE. Si escribes el comentario en formato respuesta la aceptaré como correcta.

Answer (score 6):

Sería correcto *hubieran*, en caso de que se refirieran a ellos/ellas.

> Me alegraba que hubieran tenido tanta suerte.

En este caso, se refiere a un hecho impersonal, *haber elecciones*, por lo que siempre va a ser **hubiera**/**hubiese**.

Answer (score 6):

Existe una regla simple: si, al pasar la oración al presente de indicativo (tal vez debas modificarla ligeramente para ello), el verbo *haber* se convierte en *hay*, tienes un caso de *verbo haber impersonal*. Y la construcción impersonal siempre va en singular.

En este caso:

*Me alegraba de que hubiera(n) nuevas elecciones.* --> *Me alegro porque hay nuevas elecciones.*

Por tanto, tenemos verbo haber impersonal y debe usarse en singular:

*Me alegraba de que hubiera nuevas elecciones.*

En cambio:

*Me alegraba de que ellos hubiera(n) venido a la fiesta.* --> *Me alegro porque ellos han venido a la fiesta.*

En este caso, el verbo *haber* se convierte en *han* y tenemos una construcción personal, que puede ir en singular o plural según el verbo. Así:

*Me alegraba de que ellos hubieran venido a la fiesta.*

Comment: Muy clara la lógica.  Excelente respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que el verbo principal está en imperfecto (me alegraba), el verbo de la subordinada 
"haber" (en su forma impersonal) debe llevar el auxiliar *haber* en imperfecto de subjuntivo, o sea que queda "me alegraba de que hubiera /hubiese habido elecciones".

Answer (score -3):

Aunque se trate de un sustantivo con significado singular, se coordina (los que se conjugan son los verbos) en plural:

```
Vamos a votar a las Elecciones Europeas del día 25.
```

Así pues

```
Me alegraba de que hubieran nuevas elecciones.
```

Comment: Creo que el plural no es correcto. Echa un vistazo al otro comentario que he añadido a esta pregunta.

Comment: Puede que tengas razón, no debido al singular sino al impersonal. Pon tu propia Respuesta, para que el OP la pueda elegir.